# tableview appear to be nil in ViewController when it's root by a navigation controller [SWIFT 3]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having an issue with my current project. 
At the beginning my main focus was to create a overlay button in a TableViewController but i saw that it was more simple to use a ViewController and set on it a tableView :

```
class MemoList : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTableView.delegate = self
        #datasource is linked manually in the StoryBoard
        ...
    }
}
```

When this View Controller is set as the initial controller, everything work fine but in my case, when the projet is rooted by a navigation controller, the tableview appears to be nil in the context of the 'Memolist' (when pushing on it).

Do you have any idea about this issue ? And how can I solve it ?

Thanks,

Comment: Check in your `viewDidAppear` if your `UITableView` is still nil?

Comment: In fact yes :/, I solve my issue by creating my tableView programaticaly but I don't understand where the issue came from.

Comment: How did you push the MemoList into the navigation controller?  You shouldn't have to do it manually. Simply select the view controller in the storyboard, and select "embed in-> navigation controller" from the edit menu

Comment: My ViewController was already embed in the navigation controller trough a TabBarController. Do I have to embed in an new NavigationController in MemoList, it does not make sense. I wanted all my project to embed in one single NavigationController. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that I used

```
present(myViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

After I tried to use segue and

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "myIdentifier", sender: self)
```

it worked properly and tableView was no longer nil.

Why did I have this problem:
When you use `present()`, you initialise the `View Controller` from code and it doesn't watch on your `Storyboard`. When you use `segues`, it uses the `Storyboard` and of course see all you did in your `Interface Builder`

You also can:

```
UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerId")
```

This creates view controller from Storyboard, so that tableView is initialized now